# Update centroids in minibatch K-Means

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I wish to know about the operation of minibatch KMeans through a very simple algorithm. **The aim of this post is to know how should one update centers in minibatch KMeans.** I intend to integrate minibatch in my self written KMeans code in C++ once I get the implementation clarified.

I am referring to [this paper for minibatch KMeans](https://www.eecs.tufts.edu/%7Edsculley/papers/fastkmeans.pdf). Following is a picture of the algorithm.

[image]

My KMeans algorithm already gives me cluster centroids and all points corresponding to a given centroid once I give it data.

I will try to explain my present understanding of minibatch KMeans clustering algorithm through a very simple example. Lets say that there are 15 data points in total. Following are the data points:

```
X  = [[1.0, 10.0], [1.5, 15.0], [2.0, 20.0], [2.5, 25.0], [8.0, 80.0], [8.5, 85.0], [9.0, 95.0], [10.0, 100.0], [30.0, 60.0], [31.0, 62.0], [32.0, 64.0], [33.0, 66.0], [34.0, 68.0], [35.0, 70.0], [36.0, 72.0]]
```

This is how I have interpreted the algorithm:

**Step 1.** Choose number of number of centers `n = 3`; minibatch (`M`) size `b = 10`; iterations `t = 3`.

**Step 2.** Start iteration = 0.

**Step 3.** Randomly choose minibatch `M =  [[1.0, 10.0], [1.5, 15.0], [2.5, 25.0], [8.0, 80.0], [8.5, 85.0], [9.0, 95.0], [31.0, 62.0], [33.0, 66.0], [34.0, 68.0], [35.0, 70.0]]`

**Step 4.** Randomly choose three centroids, `c1, c2, c3` from `M`. Say `c1 = [1.5, 15.0], c2=[8.5, 85.0], c3=[34.0, 68.0]`. Lets say that the clusters corresponing to the three centroids are, `cluster1 = [[1.0, 10.0], [1.5, 15.0], [2.5, 25.0]]`,  `cluster2 = [[8.0, 80.0], [8.5, 85.0], [9.0, 95.0]]` and `cluster3 = [[31.0, 62.0], [33.0, 66.0], [34.0, 68.0], [35.0, 70.0]]`.

**Step 5.** Get number of points (cardinality) in each cluster. The cardinalities of clusters corresponding to centroids, `c1, c2, c3` are `3, 3, 4` respectively.

**Step 6.** Get learning rates as reciprocal of cardinalities. The learning rates corresponding to centroids, `c1, c2, c3` are `1/3, 1/3, 1/4` respectively.

**Step 7.** Iterate over points in minibatch `M` to get new centroids, i.e.

`c1_new = (1-1/3)*[1.5, 15.0] + (1/3) * ([1.0, 10.0] + [1.5, 15.0] + [2.5, 25.0]) = [ 2.66666667, 26.66666667]`

`c2_new = (1-1/3)*[8.5, 85.0] + (1/3) * ([8.0, 80.0] + [8.5, 85.0] + [9.0, 95.0]) = [ 14.16666667, 143.33333333]`

`c3_new = (1-1/4)*[34.0, 68.0] + (1/4) * ([31.0, 62.0] + [33.0, 66.0] + [34.0, 68.0] + [35.0, 70.0]) = [ 58.75, 117.5 ]`

**Step 8.** Choose new minibatch `M_new`. Say, `M_new =  [[1.0, 10.0], [2.0, 20.0], [2.5, 25.0], [8.0, 80.0], [8.5, 85.0], [10.0, 100.0], [30.0, 60.0], [33.0, 66.0], [34.0, 68.0], [36.0, 72.0]]`.

**Step 9.** Find closest points from `c1_new, c2_new, c3_new` (from Step 7) to `M_new`. That is `[ 2.5, 25. ]`, `[ 10., 100.]` and `[ 36., 72. ]` as new centers respectively.

**Step 10.** Repeat steps 2, 5, 6, 8, 9 till maximum iteration = 3 is reached.

I am majorly concerned if I am doing Step 7., that is update of centroids correctly. Something in Step 7 does not seem to be correct in my implementation. The new centroids in the given example in Step 7 seem to be very big and out of the center.

In the above mentioned paper (refer to the picture for algorithm), the per center counts are initialized and set to 0 in line index = 3 which is before the for loop for iterations. It seems that the per center counts, which are updated in line index = 11, will only but keep increasing with each iteration. That would not seem right. Also, in line indices = 11, 12, it seems that the per center counts and learning rate are being done for specific points and not for specific clusters. That would not seem right either. Or, perhaps, I am not understanding the algorithm correctly.

**How should I update the centers and find the new centers? Can you please explain with reference to the small example data which I have given here?** Thanks in advance.